# How can I solve ERR-1002 in Oracle APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Good morning, I'm trying to reference an Interactive Grid column in a PL/SQL Code (Dynamic action) by coding in the file the column name in this way: **:CODE**. APEX PL/SQL editor doesn't throws me any error buy when I render my application, APEX debugger throws me the following error:

`ERR-1002: Unable to find item ID for item :CODE in application ...`

I tried to remake some configurations in the APEX editor, but all seems OK. I don't uderstand the error origin

Thank you in advance

I tried to make an APEX dynamic action buy it throws me an error

Comment: Can you document a reproducible case (preferrably on the emp sample data set) so I can have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can only reference interactive grid columns in dynamic actions on specific interactive grid events OR on change of an interactive grid column. Any other dynamic actions (eg on page load) cannot reference the IG columns.
I tried the following:

- Create editable IG on emp table
- Create page item P1_ENAME
- Create dynamic action on change of ENAME column of IG

  - Add true action of

    - type: "Execute Server Side Code"
    - items to submit: "ENAME"
    - items to return: "P1_ENAME"
    - PL/SQL Code:

```
:P1_ENAME := :ENAME;
```

- Add true action of

  - type: "Alert"
  - Message: "Name:  &P1_ENAME."

And it works fine.

However, if I create a DA on page load that references :ENAME column then I get the error you encountered.